# How to hide a div onload and need to show on a button click?

Tags: css

I need to hide a div onload and need to this div in a button click

```
<input id="abcd" type="button" value="display" />
<div id="xyz" style="height:600px;width:1000px;background-color:black">
    <div style="height: 350px; width: 250px; background-color: red; float: right;margin-right:30px;margin-top:100px;">
        <h1>Charaacters</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 350px; width: 250px; background-color: green; float: left; margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 100px; ">
        <h1>Translated Words</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 350px; width: 250px; background-color: yellow; float: left; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px; ">
        <h1>Translation</h1>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="button" value="trans" />
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my script,but it doesn't work

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#xyz").hide();
        $("#abcd").click(function () {
        $("#xyz").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by need to this div in a button click? did you mean show it again on button click, then use         `$("#xyz").show(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `hide()` inside button click function, change that to `show()`.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#xyz").hide();
        $("#abcd").click(function () {
        $("#xyz").show(); //This should be show
        });
    });
```

See the working fiddle here: "https://jsfiddle.net/gpfzassv/"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#xyz").hide();
        $("#abcd").click(function () {
            $("#xyz").toggle();
        });
    });
```